# Validation not work in my registration code php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want the user registration by the database

and after user set the database name and password and confirm password I store error message in sessions and display in html form

i use if to check  the condition if not will send the user to the html and display the error.

but when I run the code just the valid

rgstrhtml.php

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">


    <p class="sign" align="center">Create Account</p>
    <form class="form1" action="rgstr.php" method="post">


        <input class="input " type="text" align="center" name="database_uname" id="database_uname" required />


        <input class="input" type="text" align="center" placeholder="User Name"  name="txt_uname" id ="txt_uname" required  />
        <input class="input" type="email" align="center" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
        <input class="input" type="password" align="center" size = "25" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required />

        <input class="input" type="password" align="center" size = "25" id="copassword" name="copassword" placeholder="confirm password" required />

        <input class="submit" type="submit" align="center" id="submit" name="sign_up" value="Sign Up"  />


        <center>
            <br/>
            <a >Already have account? &nbsp</a> <a href="login.php" align="center" class="forgot"> Sign In</a>
            <br/>

        </center>

    </form>
</div>


<?php


if(isset($_SESSION["error2"])){
    $error2= $_SESSION["error2"];
    echo "<p class='error'> $error2   </p>";
}
if(isset($_SESSION["error3"])){
    $error3= $_SESSION["error3"];
    echo "<p class='error'> $error3   </p>";
}

if(isset($_SESSION["error4"])){
    $error4= $_SESSION["error4"];
    echo "<p class='error'> $error4   </p>";
}
?>

</body>

</html>


<?php
unset($_SESSION["error2"]);
unset($_SESSION["error3"]);
unset($_SESSION["error4"]);
?>
```

rgsrt.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'database.php';

if(isset($_POST['sign_up'])) {
    $databasenam = $_POST['database_uname'];
    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $copassword = $_POST['copassword'];

    $error2 = "* Passwords do not match. ";
    $error3 = "* Passwords should be 8 digits at least.";
    $error4 = "* This database name was taken, please try another.";

    $sqll = "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '$databasenam'";
    $resultt =  mysqli_query($conn, $sqll);
    if($resultt->num_rows) {
        $_SESSION["error4"] = $error4;
        header('Location: rgstrhtml.php');
    }

    if ($password != $copassword) {
        $_SESSION["error2"] = $error2;
        header('Location: rgstrhtml.php');
    }

    if (strlen($password) < 8) {
        $_SESSION["error3"] = $error3;
        header('Location: rgstrhtml.php');
    }
    else {
        $resultc = mysqli_query($conn, " CREATE DATABASE " . $databasenam . "");

        $use_query = "use " . $databasenam . "";
        $resultuse = mysqli_query($conn, $use_query);

        $admin_query = "CREATE TABLE admin (
    id    int   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    admin_name  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    admin_pass  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    admin_email VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ) ";
        $resultadmin = mysqli_query($conn, $admin_query);
        $sqla = "INSERT INTO admin (admin_name ,admin_pass , admin_email)VALUES('$uname','$password','$email')";
        $resultinsertadmn = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['inv'] = $databasenam;
        header('Location: session.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: why voting down the answer it is not correct? and @Strawberry what do you mean?

Comment: @Dharman Okay I will use prepared statements thanks for tell me.

Answer (score -1):

The `else` block that creates the database is only connected to `if (strlen($password) >= 8)`. So you'll execute it even if the other validations fail, as long as the password is long enough.

You need to check all the errors, and skip creating the database.

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'database.php';

if(isset($_POST['sign_up'])) {
    $databasenam = $_POST['database_uname'];
    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $copassword = $_POST['copassword'];

    $error2 = "* Passwords do not match. ";
    $error3 = "* Passwords should be 8 digits at least.";
    $error4 = "* This database name was taken, please try another.";

    $any_error = false;

    $sqll = "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '$databasenam'";
    $resultt =  mysqli_query($conn, $sqll);
    if($resultt->num_rows) {
        $_SESSION["error4"] = $error4;
        $any_error = true;
    }

    if ($password != $copassword) {
        $_SESSION["error2"] = $error2;
        $any_error = true;
    }

    if (strlen($password) < 8) {
        $_SESSION["error3"] = $error3;
        $any_error = true;
    }

    if ($any_error) {
        header('Location: rgstrhtml.php');
        exit();
    }

    $resultc = mysqli_query($conn, " CREATE DATABASE " . $databasenam . "");

    $use_query = "use " . $databasenam . "";
    $resultuse = mysqli_query($conn, $use_query);

    $admin_query = "CREATE TABLE admin (
                        id    int   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        admin_name  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
                        admin_pass  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
                        admin_email VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL UNIQUE
                    ) ";
    $resultadmin = mysqli_query($conn, $admin_query);
    $sqla = "INSERT INTO admin (admin_name ,admin_pass , admin_email)VALUES('$uname','$password','$email')";
    $resultinsertadmn = mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);

    $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
    $_SESSION['inv'] = $databasenam;
    header('Location: session.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: I am not sure why this was downvoted. However, I would probably have just followed up the `header(Location: xxx)` statements with a call to `exit()`.

Comment: @Booboo He apparently wants to be able to display multiple validation messages, so it shouldn't exit immediately after the `header()` calls.

Comment: Well then `exit()` would certainly be inappropriate. But how many times can you issue the `Location:` header? I would probably set that header once `if ($any_error)`. But that's all besides the point. I still don't understand why the 3 downvotes.

Comment: @Booboo I don't think there's a problem with multiple location headers, especially if they're all the same location. But I agree that doing it once would be cleaner.